# Getting variables From a config file to the browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, iframe

I have a rather complex setup which requires the web browser local storage has the computer's name populated in order for the application to work properly. In order to do this I read from a configuration file:

```
kiosk-name: Mort
```

I read the config file when I start my node.js web server:

```
var filesys = require('fs');
var os = require('os');

filesys.readFile(project_path + '/kiosk.cfg', 'utf8', function(err, data) {
    var kioskname;
    if (err) {
        //console.log(err);
        kioskname = os.hostname();
    } else {
        var configArray = data.split(':');
        if('' != configArray[1]) {
            kioskname = configArray[1];
        } else {
            kioskname = os.hostname();
        }
    }
});
```

All of this works as designed, using the computer's `os.hostname()` as a default when the config file is not populated.

The client side features a base page (index.html) which loads a default page (default.html) into an `iframe`. Based on a websocket messaging system the default page gets replaced by another page from a remote IP. **In an older version of the system** (prior to implementing a config file) we were able to set the local storage element with the following code:

```
var win = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].contentWindow;
win.postMessage(JSON.stringify({key: 'kiosk-name', data: kioskName}), "*");
```

We identify the iframe when the websocket message is received and then send a post message containing a JSON string to set the local storage element. In this case `kioskName` is a variable containing a hard-coded value.

**The Problem**

Now that we wish to read values from a config file we need a way to pass `kioskname` out to the client-side JavaScript so we can set the local storage element in the `iframe`.

I attempted putting the file reading function in an `export` wrapper:

```
(function(exports){

    // file reading code here
    return kioskname;

})(typeof exports === 'undefined' ? this['kioskname']={} : exports);
```

I got an error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Placing a static value in the `export` function (with out the `require`'s allows the export function to work properly, but doesn't allow me to read the config file which requires both the `os` and `fs` modules.

How do I get the value returned from the config file to a place where I can use it on the client-side to set a local storage element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a creative solution which may not be suitable for every case as it involves utilizing a websocket between the Node.js web server and the client.

Websocket setup to send to client (assumes webserver at '`node_server`':

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(node_server); // 'attaches' socket.io to this web server

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.emit('message', 'socket.io connected'); // output a connection message
    // receive JSON message and send to the websocket
    socket.on('message', function (data) {
        var address = node_server.address();
        var client = dgram.createSocket("udp4");
        var message = new Buffer(data);
        // out of the airlock!
        client.send(message, 0, message.length, address.port, address.address, function(err, bytes) {
            client.close();
        });
    });
});
```

Read the config file, then parse and send a message to the socket (done on the server-side):

```
filesys.readFile(project_path + '/kiosk.cfg', 'utf8', function(err, data) {
    var kioskname;
    if (err) {
        //console.log(err);
        kioskname = os.hostname();
    } else {
        var configArray = data.split(':');
        if('' != configArray[1]) {
            kioskname = configArray[1];
        } else {
            kioskname = os.hostname();
        }
    }
    // create JSON string for transmission
    KioskName = JSON.stringify({'config':{'kiosk-name': kioskname}});
    var send_KioskName = setInterval(function(){ // could be a setTimeout for a one time send
        io.sockets.emit('message', KioskName.toString()); // send config file data to browser via socket
    }, 30000);

});
```

> **NOTE** this *can* be expanded to send multiple pieces of data via JSON to the client should the need arise. A couple of small edits are all that is needed to setup a more detailed JSON object.

Receive the socket message on the client side (this code is loaded by the client), then parse. The resulting object is added to the namespace for this application, making the object available to multiple scripts when required.

> **CAUTION: You should only use this methodology for objects which do not interfere with objects you may create or destroy in your scripts along the way.**

```
// make sure a string is JSON before using
function isJSON(str) {
    try {
        JSON.parse(str);
        return true;
    } catch (e) {
        return false;
    }
}

// set up object 'array's
var kioskname = {};

// connect a socket to listen for incoming messages from the Big Giant Head
var socket = io();
socket.on('message', function (data) {

    if(isJSON(data)) {
        // parse the json
        var json = $.parseJSON(data);

        // determine how to use this JSON object, multiple objects may be sent
        if('config' == Object.keys(json)[0]) {
            /*
             * send config data where needed - future proofed, just add cases
             * and namespaced objects where required
             */
            kioskname['name'] = json.config['kiosk-name'];


        }
    }
});

// attach objects to namespace
window.KIOSK.kioskname = kioskname;
```

Now we can use the object to set local storage. *In our case* we post a message to the app's server and it responds with `localStorage.setItem()`:

Post the message:

```
var currentFrame = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].contentWindow;
currentFrame.postMessage(JSON.stringify({key: 'user-name', data: KIOSK.kioskname.name}), "*");
```

By opening a socket and using the JSON string passed through the socket to populate a namespaced object we are able to use server-side information from a configuration file in our application's client.